# How to connect two view controller to one view controller using Storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I'm trying to connect two view controller into a one controller. As you can see below picture, when "plus" item is tapped the screen came and it works well. However, the other segue doesn't work properly. With my first tapping to any row, it doesn't take me to the view but after first tapping it starts taking me to the view as I wanted. I couldn't figure out why it doesn't take me to when I firstly tap any row. Here is the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    DovizDetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
}
```

Below is my storyboard. The problem is about with the above view and it's segue.

[image: Two view connected to one]

Hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Hahaha that was clearly stupid of mine :D Sometimes the errors are so minorly hidden that you never see, tho. Thanks a lot !